# Power Bi, Dax Syntax to subtract TODAY date with criteria from a column with repeated dates

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, subtraction

The problem is, I have table with products, their "adresses" and the expiration date, just like below:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uVRU.png)

I need to show the "days to expire" in a matrix-visual so I tried to make a DAX formula as it goes trying to get the "days to expire" from each product and it's expiration date uniquely, but the result was way far from what i wanted.

```
DaysToExpire = CONVERT(SUM(Venda_Abast_Venc[DTVALIDADE]) - TODAY(), INTEGER)
```

It resulted in the sum of all the expirations dates by product and subtracted by the Today() date, the number was really higher than the real value when I needed it uniquely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward, add a new column:

```
DaysToExpire = DateDiff(Today(), Venda_Abast_Venc[DTVALIDADE], DAY)
```

Comment: It worked as a table while looking at the powerquery, but when i use that as a Matrix it will sum again since the expiration dates won't be repeating.

Comment: you need to use the option Don't sum. On teh visual input. You will need to add more details to your question when you work with visuals because you do not mention this at all..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: what happens if your matrix selection brings more than one product with different expiration dates? Assuming the safest option, I'll use the minimum expiration date.

```
DaysToExpire =
INT( MIN( Venda_Abast_Venc[DTVALIDADE] ) - TODAY() )
```

this way dates are not summed up and just one date is selected for the computation